# Prevent retrofit from encoding my http request body

Tags: java, json, retrofit

I'm trying to pass a string of the format below as the body of a http post request.

```
param1=PARAM1&param2=PARAM2&param3=PARAM3
```

But retrofit encodes my body so that = becomes \u003d and & becomes \u0026. And I end up with a string which actually looks like this:

```
param1\u003dPARAM1\u0026param2\u003dPARAM2\u0026param3\u003dPARAM3
```

How can I prevent that?

My retrofit rest api is defined as follows.

```java
public interface RestAPI {
    @POST("/oauth/token")
    public void getAccessToken(@Body String requestBody, Callback<Response> response);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer the question directly, you can use `TypedString` as the method parameter type. The reason the value is being changed is because Retrofit is handing the `String` to Gson in order to encode as JSON. Using `TypedString` or any `TypedOutput` subclass will prevent this behavior, basically telling Retrofit you will handle creating the direct request body yourself.

However, that format of payload is called form URL encoding. Retrofit has native support for it. Your method declaration should actually look like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/oauth/token")
void getAccessToken(
    @Field("param1") String param1,
    @Field("param2") String param2,
    @Field("param3") String param3,
    Callback<Response> callback);
```

Comment: I'm trying to POST body as class but some variables in it contains encrypted strings like "66PdGFKsvyyYaVTGJ/nAYQ==" ... any idea how to prevent the = signs from converting to \u003d

Answer (score 11):

If you have a serialized class (like a HashMap) in the request body and you want to prevent encoding that (like in vezikon's and my problem), you can create a custom Gson with disabled escaping using:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
```

Pass this converter to your rest adapter:

```
yourRestAdapter  = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(.....)
    .setClient(.....)
    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
    .build();
```

This way the "=" characters in the post body stay intact while submitting.

Comment: inretrofit 2, we can't use it like this

Comment: Well, this answer is from Retrofit 1 days, but can't you use it the same way in Retrofit 2 like this? (I haven't tested it):

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).client(okHttpClient).build();

Comment: what is RestAdapter?@MuratÖgat

Comment: Its not working for Retrofit 2. Kindly suggest some other way

Answer (score 2):

**Using Kotlin**

For Retrofit 2 you can initialize retrofit with a Gson converter factory.

```
val builder = GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create()
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(builder))
        .client(monoOkHttpClient())
        .build()
```

This builder should remove escaping from your json output.

**Gradle file dependencies:**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

Comment: thats not worked for me. i am using ''com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'' && ''com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0''. Please help me

Comment: @RahulGupta You need Scalars too. `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'`

I've added the deps to my answer.

Comment: its not supporting..Please check.. 
'     private static final RestAdapter REST_ADAPTER =
            new RestAdapter
                    .Builder()
                    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson)) // To avoid sending Encoded Special character in Request
                    .setEndpoint(API_URL)
                    .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                    .setClient(new Ok3Client(new OkHttpClient()))
                    .build();
'

Answer (score -1):

This issue can be fixed with below workaround.

```
@POST("yourString")
Call<YourResponseModel> yourCallMethod(@Query("yourKey") String yourValue,
                                          @Query("yourKey") String yourValue,
                                          @Query("yourKey") String yourValue);
```

Note : Don't use "@FormUrlEncoded" for this case.

[Reference Here - https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1407](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1407)