# Retrofit encodes Body

Tags: android, character-encoding, retrofit

I have an API call to make. I am using Retrofit to make the call like below:

```
  @POST("/speak?api-version=2.0")
  Observable<Response> testAPICall(
        @Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
        @Body String text,
        @Query("language") String languageCode,
      );
```

I am calling the API like:

```
String bodyString = "<markerbegin>blah<markerend/>";
testAPICall("application/ssml+xml", bodyString,"en-US");
```

Problem is that, the bodyString  gets encoded. So, the '<' or '>'  or '/' etc. getting encoded as /u003 etc.

Searching SO didn't help. I tried - using FormUrlEncoding, which didn't compile and also passing the body as bytes[] but that failed as well.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent retrofit from encoding my http request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637340/prevent-retrofit-from-encoding-my-http-request-body)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the signature from String to TypedString:

from  @Body String text --> @Body TypedString text,

```
Observable<Response> testAPICall(
    @Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
    @Body TypedString text,
    @Query("language") String languageCode,
  );
```

Instead of passing a String, I passed: new TypedString(theText)