# POST with retrofit,with encoding

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm sending a POST request and passing the link, but all the {} and [] are encrypted in% 7B,% 22 I tried URLDecoder did not help, tell me please how I can solve it. Thank you.

```
@Multipart
    @POST("entity/api/xm-entities/self/links/targets/{link}")
    Call<ResponseBody> sendPhoto(
            @Header("Authorization") String token,
            @Path("link") String link,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

try to decode

```
String link = obj.toString();
    String afterDecode = null;

    try {
        afterDecode = URLDecoder.decode(link, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Link try to send

```
{"typeKey":"typekeyName","target":{"typeKey" : "typeKeyName","name":"<filename>","tags":[{"name": "photo_name"}]}}
```

After sending

```
%7B%22typeKey%22:%22typekeyName%22,%22target%22:%7B%22typeKey%22:%22typekeyName%22,%22name%22:%22%3Cfilename%3E%22,%22tags%22:[%7B%22name%22:%22photo_name%22%7D]%7D%7D}
```

Comment: @Query(value = "link", encoded = true)

Comment: http://square.github.io/retrofit/ try to add another part like documentation says

Comment: Did you try with something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29291614/4162647